# How to address a node using an attribute in a filter

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, freemarker

I am a newbie to FreeMarker. So far I have only used XSLT and I wanted to have a look at FreeMarker as a replacement.

I have the following ftl template (only the relevant parts)

`<#assign deelnemer = body.document[0].form[0].panel[0]>`
`<#assign UPO = body.document[0].form[0].pensioenGegevens[0]>`
...
`<div>Document ${body.document.@docId}</div>`
`<h1>Wijzig gebruiker ${deelnemer.field["@name='name'"]}</h1>`

and the following content

`<document docId="1">`
`<form>`
`<panel id="deelnemer">`
`<field type="text" name="name" id="name">Jansen</field>`
`<field type="text" name="dateOfBirth" id="dateOfBirth">02-07-1971</field>`
`<field type="text" name="dateOfEnlistment" id="dateOfEnlistment">01-01-2013</field>`
`<field type="hidden" name="OIDDln" id="OIDDln">1</field>`
`<field type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" nextPage="response2">Wijzig</field>`
`</panel>`
`<pensioenGegevens/>`
`</form>`
`</document>`

I was hoping to get the value Jansen when using the expression ${deelnemer.field["@name='name'"]}, but instead of this I get an exception

Cannot perform an XPath query against a node set of 5 nodes. Expecting a single node.

### The problematic instruction:

### ==> ${body.document[0].form[0].panel[0].field["@name='name'"][0]} [on line 23, column 28 in deelnemer.ftl]

### Java backtrace for programmers:

freemarker.template.TemplateModelException: Cannot perform an XPath query against a node set of 5 nodes. Expecting a single node.

If I use deelnemer.field[0] I see the name Jansen appear as expected. So I get the feeling that the given XPath expression does not work.

Could someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: The error message originally contained deelnemer which I replaced with body.document[0].form[0].panel[0] just to see if there is a difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error message tries to convey, you can only issue an XPath query against a single node (or 0 nodes). As far as I remember this is (or was back then when FM was written) a limitation of the public API of Xalan, not of FreeMarker strictly speaking. So try to use Jaxen instead, which has (or had) a much less limiting API. Put it into the class path, and call `NodeModel.useJaxenXPathSupport()` at some early point.

Another solution is to write `${body.document[0].form[0].panel[0]["field/@name='name'"][0]}` of course, as then you avoid issuing XPath against multiple nodes.

BTW, it's unrelated, but I don't think you need all (maybe none of) those `[0]`-s. Like since you have only one `document`-s, `document[0]` is practically the same as `document`.

Comment: Thank you. I am now using Jaxen and now I get the following error

Comment: Sorry, something is missing: Error on line 25, column 30 in deelnemer.ftl
Expression deelnemer.field["@name='name'"] is not numerical
Expression field is not numerical
The problematic instruction:
----------
==> ${deelnemer.field["@name='name'"]/field} [on line 25, column 28 in deelnemer.ftl]
----------

Java backtrace for programmers:
----------
freemarker.core.NonNumericalException: Error on line 25, column 30 in deelnemer.ftl
Expression deelnemer.field["@name='name'"] is not numerical
Expression field is not numerical

Comment: Because you have put the `/` outside the quotation marks, so it means division.

Comment: Thank you, you are right. I corrected the expression and now I get the following error: Expecting a string, date or number here, Expression deelnemer.field["@name='name'"] is instead a freemarker.template.TemplateBooleanModel$2
The problematic instruction:
----------
==> ${deelnemer.field["@name='name'"]} [on line 24, column 28 in deelnemer.ftl]
freemarker.core.NonStringException: Error on line 24, column 30 in deelnemer.ftl

Comment: Because that XPath expression (`@name='name'`) has indeed a boolean result. You meant `${deelnemer["field[@name='name']"]}` (select the `field` *where* `@name='name'`).

Comment: Thank you Daniel. That's it. I really need to get used to this approach. It's a bit different from XSLT.

Comment: The thing that should be realized is that FreeMarker doesn't support XML transformations or XML in general on the language-level. It's just a trick with the type-system API of FreeMarker that's technically just an extension that could be 3rd party as well. BTW, you are supposed to Accept my answer if it was correct.